# In EF4.1 code first, how to override ConnectionString name in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm creating a multi-tenant Asp.Net MVC 3 Web app, and using EF4.1 code first for the db model.

For development I'm happy to use SqlServerCE in App_Data, and for production this will move to Sql Server 2008.

Say my context is called "MyModels", by default code-first looks for a connection string called "MyModels" in Web.config. This can be told to use a file in App_Data or changed to access a database in SQL2008. All fine so far.

But because of multi-tenancy, I'd like the SqlServerCE filename to match the unique id of the tenant (so App_Data would have "client_x.sdf", "client_y.sdf"; Sql Server 2008 would have separate databases). I can't work out how to direct to these different databases.

I've tried MyModels inheriting from DbContext and supplying a connection string (using a 'placeholder' conn string in Web.config and replacing "{clientId}" with the unique id), and I've also tried setting the connection string in the MyModels constructor:

```
base.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = xxx;
```

but this never seems to work. I always get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

(This suggests it's not yet 'configured' to use SqlServerCE, and so is trying to connect to Sql Server. I think!)

Tracing the code, Database.Connection.ConnectionString hasn't been read from Web.config at this point, so I can't search and replace that, and, possibly, it's getting overwritten by the 'placeholder' conn string later in the pipeline.

I reckon this must be quite straightforward and I just can't find the 'hook'. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I've figured it out, and it's because I'm a bit dumb. Sorry! I was just trying to set the ConnectionString to be the connectionString from Web.config, but I actually need to build it using the DbConnectionStringBuilder. If I replace the ConnectionString property of the builder, then use the builder to set the EF conn string, it works. I could do with marking this as solved, please!

Comment: Write the content of your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: As Ladislav Mrnka states, it's perfectly OK to answer your own question. I believe you have to wait a day or so before you can mark your own answer as "the" answer, but it is allowed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, and it's because I'm a bit dumb. Sorry! I was just trying to set the ConnectionString to be the connectionString from Web.config, but I actually need to build it using the DbConnectionStringBuilder. If I replace the ConnectionString property of the builder, then use the builder to set the EF conn string, it works.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors. A bit of code showing what part makes the string web.config and how to set it otherwise would be of MUCH help to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a possible approach to solve your problem.
My idea is to create a static "factory" class to instantiate your DbContext class. The code is like this:

```
public static class MyModelsFactory
{
    public static MyModels CreateMyModels()
    {
        string connectionString = string.Empty;
        // some code to retrieve your connectionString.
        return new MyModels(connectionString);
    }
}
```

And you may call CreateMyModels method wherever you need to instantiate MyModels class:

```
using (MyModels models = MyModelsFactory.CreateMyModels())
{
    //your code
}
```

It works for me in the case I need to change the connection string according to some logic at runtime. But my DbContext class is generated automatically by classic EF, not code first.